# Как добавлять данные в "События" средства диагностики?

Tags: visual-studio, отладка

Как добавить события сюда?
Я так полагаю в коде можно что-то писать, и при наступлении этого события оно будет попадать в это окно... Не могу найти инфу, как это сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]